# Do I need to pay the visa fee separately for all of my party?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, fees-and-charges, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian applying for a UK Visa for me & my wife & my daughter. I have already finished my UK Visa application and paid the fee, but on registering with TLSContact Process, i saw the message below;

> If you are planning to travel with family members (parents, spouse, children), it is mandatory to have each person in registered the same group. This also applies to unrelated persons who plan to travel together on the same itinerary.
>
> Here is the list of applicants for this group.
>   Click on the name of an applicant to change any information.
>   Children on parent's passport should be individually filled in this group.

From the above message I think it implies that I have to fill another UK visa application form for my wife and daughter and pay the UK VISA fee too. Please help me to know if I am right or if the message should be ignored.

Comment: What kind of visa? To where?

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. I do not know the answer but expect some of the other users here will know.

Comment: Every visitor needs a separate visa, @David.

Comment: @EwigeStudentin Thanks for the poke. You're correct, and I've deleted my comment.